# WebGL - GLSL - What's the difference between vec3.rgb and vec3.xyz?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, color-space

What is the difference between using `.rgb` and `.xyz` when dealing with a `vec3` in a GLSL shader?

For example, in some examples I see `.rgb`:

```
void main() {
    vec3 color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0); // <-- using color.rgb
}
```

But in other examples I see `.xyz`:

```
void main() {
    vec3 color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.xyz, 1.0); // <-- using color.xyz
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real difference. They're "syntactic sugar" for referencing the same data.

See: [Data type "swizzling"](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling)